# Loop Javascript - 1 + input

Tags: javascript, loop

Boa noite, pessoal!

Estou travado num loop de Javascript, é o seguinte:

Usuário digita um número positivo qualquer, exemplo 15.

Preciso disponibilizar no console o número 1 até 15.

O problema é que não sei como devo incrementar um número que não sei qual será digitado e ainda por cima limitar este número do número 1 até o digitado.

Deu pra entender ou tá confuso?

Obrigado.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Por favor explique melhor o problema, e se possível inclua um exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo, pois não está perceptível a sua pergunta. Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar.

Answer (score 2):

Encontre abaixo a resposta a sua pergunta, penso que a duvida seria como buscar o valor do **input** `document.getElementById(ID_DO_ELEMENTO).value`

```js
document.getElementById('go').onclick = function() { //attribui um evento click para o button[go]
  var numero = document.getElementById('numero').value; //busca o valor dentro do input[numero]
  if (isFinite(numero)) { //verifica se e numero
    for (var x = 1; x <= numero; x++) { //loop de 1 ate numero introduzido
      console.log(x); //escreve na consola os valores de x
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<h3>Loop Javascript - 1 + input</h3>
<input type="text" id="numero" placeholder="Introduza um numero" />
<button id="go">Go</button>
```

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado. Não sabia como definir isso no FOR.